# passing html information through javascript to php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have two textboxes that are normally disabled.  When a user presses a edit button the textbox becomes enabled and they are allowed to type.  However when I submit the form the value that was input by the user is not passed to my php code.

Here is my javascript code:

```
if (timesin%2 == 0){
    document.getElementById(score1).disabled = true;
    document.getElementById(score2).disabled = true;
} else {
    document.getElementById(score1).disabled = false;
    document.getElementById(score2).disabled = false;
    document.getElementById(score1).value = "";
    document.getElementById(score2).value = "";
}
timesin++;
```

Here on each alternate clicks it disables or enables, probably not the best way to do this but thats not the important part here.

This is the html code for the box

```
<input type = 'textbox' id = 'columntext".$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]."' name = 'columntext".$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]."'  maxlength = '2' disabled style = 'width:15px; text-align:center' value = '".$col_value."' />
```

So it is disabled.  When a button is clicked the function is called and the textbox is enabled.  The user then types a value and clicks the edit button again which disables the textbox.  So now I have the textbox disabled with a new inputted valued.  However when I submit and get the value through php I get a blank variable.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you read the values of textboxes using php? can you show your code?

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type = 'textbox' id = 'columntext".$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]."' name = 'columntext".$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]."'  maxlength = '2' disabled style = 'width:15px; text-align:center' value = '".$col_value."' />
```

I see a couple of problems. One is that .$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]. isn't HTML. You need the php tags around it and also need to echo those values, which would look like this:

```
'columntext<?php echo $columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues] ?>'
```

Same thing with this line:

```
 value = '".$col_value."'
```

should be

```
 value = '<?php echo $col_value ?>'
```

I'm surprised the page rendered, unless you were preparing it within a php echo all along? Either way, clarifying that bit might help narrow down what the problem *could* be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear enough but... any disabled input is not going to be sent, if you want to be no-editable try with readonly='readonly', and BTW you should make some kind of validation in your php code, don't trust in JS only

good luck

Comment: in js would I remove the readonly attribute to make it editable right?

Comment: I changed the disabled to readonly.  So when I click an edit button the readonly is set to false.  I then type in the numbers but when I submit I still get the same problem.  No values are passed.

Comment: remove the readonly,use jquery function $().removeAttr(). and it will work, if not, let me know

Answer (score 0):

This is an incorrect way of using inline PHP:

```
<input type = 'textbox' id = 'columntext".$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]."' name = 'columntext".$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]."'  maxlength = '2' disabled style = 'width:15px; text-align:center' value = '".$col_value."' />
```

Instead try something like this:

```
<?php

   $id = "columntext".$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues];

?>

<input type="textbox" id="<?php echo($id); ?>" name="<?php echo($id); ?>" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo($col_value); ?>">
```

Also, you should consider using a separate CSS file to hold your styling rather than place it within the HTML element. It makes life so much easier and helps keep your design DRY.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is inside a PHP echo statement, change

```
<input type = 'textbox' id = 'columntext".$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]."' name = 'columntext".$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]."'  maxlength = '2' disabled style = 'width:15px; text-align:center' value = '".$col_value."' />
```

to

```
<textarea id = 'columntext".$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]."' name = 'columntext".$columncount.$inc.$leaguesarray[$numofleagues]."'  maxlength = '2' disabled style = 'width:15px; text-align:center'  />".$col_value."</textarea>

ive never seen <input type = 'textbox'> before
```